# Send mail in asp.net without smtp details

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sendmail

I am using asp.net and C#.

I have deployed my application on the server and now I come to know that my server would not provide me SMTP detail , is their any way I could send sms without smtp details.

I can use bot asp.net3.5 with C# or SQL Server 2005 to send mail.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send an email with C# / .NET, make use of the `System.Net.MailMessage` and `System.Net.SmtpClient` classes.

Create a new instance of the `MailMessage` class, set some properties (from, to, body, subject, etc).

Create a new instance of the `SmtpClient` class, set some properties (SMTP credentials).

Then just do `smtpClient.Send(mailMessage)`.

Pretty simple.

Comment: As I said earlier I don't have SMTP details, will the above code work without SMTP details ?

Comment: Sorry - i thought the below comment implied you had the details.

Without SMTP details, your only option in SQL Server Mail.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to send through SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260697%28SQL.80%29.aspx
If your administrators will allow it. It is debatable whether this is good practice, but I worked at one place that perfromed all of its automated emailing of error notifications for example, using xp_sendmail

Comment: Can I use any webservice to send mail ??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your server absolutely has an IP address, you just don't know what it is.  [Here](http://www.tech-pro.net/find-my-ip-address.shtml) is some information on finding out what your IP address is..

No, you cannot send or receive any kind of email without the proper server/connection information.  Otherwise, I could just send email from your account without you knowing it.

Comment: My mistake ! I corrected it to SMTP. Please let me know how to send the mail, can I use any web service ?